# new custom theme - posts displaying on top of one another

Tags: loop, templates, blog

[live blog](http://frshstudio.com/blog/)

I've just implemented a new, custom theme. I've noticed that my posts are now displaying all on top of one another and I can't figure out why. To test my code, I swapped out my custom loop for the plain Wordpress loop- the problem persisted. I've also disabled every single plugin and again, problem persists. Any ideas how to fix?

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Blog
*/
?>

<?php get_header();?>

<div id="blog-container">
    <div class="content">
    <?php get_sidebar( 'blog');?>
    <?php if(have_posts()) : while(have_posts()) : the_post(''); ?>
        <div class="meta">
            <h3><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
            <p><span style="font-size:85%"><?php the_tags('tags: ', ', ', '<br />'); ?> | <?php comments_number( 'no responses', 'one response', '% responses' ); ?> comments</span></p>
        </div><!-- end meta -->
        <div class="post">
            <?php the_content('read more...'); ?>
        </div><!-- end post -->
        <div class="share">
            <span class="left-border"></span><!-- end border -->
            <p style="font-family:nevis-webfont;">SHARE THIS POST</p>
            <span class="right-border"></span><!-- end border -->
        </div><!-- end share -->
    </div><!-- end content -->
    <?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php else : ?>
            <p>I'm not sure what you're looking for.</p>
    <?php endif; ?>
</div><!-- end blog-container -->

<?php get_footer();?>
```

Comment: This type of question is too localized for WSPE, it is most likely an error related to javascript or HTML tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have closed div having content class inside if statement which causes to break nested markup, instead close it outside if statement as following.

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Blog
*/
?>
<?php get_header();?>
<div id="blog-container">
<div class="content">
<?php get_sidebar( 'blog');?>
<?php if(have_posts()) : while(have_posts()) : the_post(''); ?>
    <div class="meta">
        <h3><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
        <p><span style="font-size:85%"><?php the_tags('tags: ', ', ', '<br />'); ?> | <?php comments_number( 'no responses', 'one response', '% responses' ); ?> comments</span></p>
    </div><!-- end meta -->
    <div class="post">
        <?php the_content('read more...'); ?>
    </div><!-- end post -->
    <div class="share">
        <span class="left-border"></span><!-- end border -->
        <p style="font-family:nevis-webfont;">SHARE THIS POST</p>
        <span class="right-border"></span><!-- end border -->
    </div><!-- end share -->

<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php else : ?>
        <p>I'm not sure what you're looking for.</p>
<?php endif; ?>
</div><!-- end content -->
</div><!-- end blog-container -->
<?php get_footer();?>
```

Comment: I'm afraid it's always the small, simple things that I miss. Thank you for your help.